# process.env inside next.config.js

Tags: heroku, next.js, nextjs-image

I'm trying to use the Next.js image optimization with an external loader. I'm at a loss as to why the following doesn't work

```
module.exports = withPlugins([withGraphql], {
  [PHASE_PRODUCTION_BUILD]: {
    webpack: (config, { webpack }) => {
      config.plugins.push(new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/\/__tests__\//))
      return config
    },
  },
  images = {
    loader: 'imgix',
    path: process.env.IMAGE_LOADER_URL,
  }
})
```

But if I hardcode the value it works. This is on Heroku and logging the value of `process.env.IMAGE_LOADER_URL` shows in the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was twofold:

1. Next.js reads this file BEFORE loading any `.env` files on build.
2. Heroku does not run `docker build` with env vars while running containerized builds.

Ultimately my solution was to abandon Dockerized builds. This also increased my deploy speed.